# How to change the value position into every one our using python stackoverflow

Tags: python, pandas, time, while-loop

Here I have a one input with date and time. So here that values are not in proper matter. Because some values measured not in exactly after one hour. My data collection like this :

```html
date      time                x
8/6/2018 6:15:00           141
8/6/2018 6:45:00                 0
8/6/2018 7:45:00          0
8/6/2018 9:00:00          0
8/6/2018 9:25:00                 95
8/6/2018 9:30:00                 0
8/6/2018 11:00:00         149
8/6/2018 11:30:00         0
8/6/2018 13:30:00         0
8/6/2018 13:50:00         85
8/6/2018 15:00:00         0
8/6/2018 15:25:00         0
8/6/2018 16:25:00         135
8/6/2018 18:00:00         0
8/6/2018 19:00:00         63
8/6/2018 19:30:00         0
8/6/2018 20:00:00        111
8/6/2018 22:05:00        115
8/6/2018 22:15:00         0
8/6/2018 23:40:00        287
```

AS you see in my dataset first I measured the x value at 6:15:00 , the value is 141. Then again 6:45:00 no value.

I want to resample the values in every one hour putting the values included in dataset.

After 6:15:00 then next is 7:15:00
So in between `6:15:00 - 7:15:00 no values then  at 7:15:00 = 0`

Then `7:15:00 - 8:15:00 no values contain in-between these two time period then at 8:15:00 = 0`

What I expected output :

[image: Expected output]

I wrote the code and it gave me an error, it doesn't show me what I expected value

my code:

```
filtered = data[data['x'] >= 0]
start_time = filtered.iloc[0]['date']
current_time = start_time
required_hours_of_generated_data = 15        # Generate data for this many hours.
x_level = {'date':[start_time], 'level':[filtered.iloc[0]['x']] }

while True:
  while True:
    next_record_time = current_time + timedelta(0,3600)
    rec = filtered[filtered['date'] > next_record_time]
    x_level['date'].append(next_record_time)
    if(len(rec) > 0):
        x_level['level'].append(rec['x'])
    else:
        x_level['level'].append(0)

    if(next_record_time + timedelta(0,3600) > start_time + timedelta(0, 3600*required_hours_of_generated_data)):
        break

       current_time = next_record_time

       rec = filtered[filtered['date'] > current_time]['date']
       if(len(rec) == 0):
         break
     start_time = min(rec)
     current_time = start_time
     rec = filtered[filtered['date'] == start_time]
   x_level['date'].append(start_time)
  x_level['level'].append(rec.iloc[0]['x'])
```

Here what I got output:

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I find your expected output confusing: you have `0` at `9:30`, yet your expected value at `10:15` is `95`. why does the value at `9:30` not override the value at `9:25`?

Comment: @00 ya because in-between time range 9:15:00 -10:15:00 there  is a value 95 at 9:25:00, so this value should have to show at 10:15:00 as  a 95. here my time delta is one hour, so start time is mine 6:15:00, then after one hour one hour I want to display value and if that time range any values are available then that value should have to display in next time range as I shown in expected output graph.